# In Sunshine (2007) what is this flashing face about?

Tags: movie, sunshine

During watching of [Sunshine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448134/) (2007) I've noticed flashing face (approximately 49'39"), when crew members were moving on the **Icarus I** board:

[image: Icarus I crew member face]

What is it about?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The flashing images were of the Icarus I crew members. While searching
>   Icarus I, Searle comes across the photo of the crew members wearing
>   Hawaiian shirts (similar to the photo of the Icarus II crew members,
>   who were wearing Santa hats).
>
> The similar photos of the two crews hint that what caused the Icarus I
>   from accomplishing its mission is what is happening to the crew of the
>   Icarus II.

Source: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448134/faq#.2.1.6

Comment: oh.. blind me - haven't find it on imdb! :)